# findFragmentByTag doesnt work

Tags: java, android

I have a problem findFragmentByTag always returns null; So I want to fix this one.

I have tried the same things with support v4, but this always returns me null

MainActivity:`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ContentFragment temp = new ContentFragment();
    t.add(R.id.content, temp, "mine");

    // it does the same
    //t.add(R.id.content, new ContentFragment(), "mine");
    //t.commitAllowingStateLoss(); // from supprt v4
    t.commit();

    //
    ContentFragment fragment = (ContentFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mine");
    if (fragment == null) Log.e("ALARM", "fragment == null");
    else fragment.callMe();
    }
}
```

ContentFragment: `

```
public class ContentFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            inflater.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            Environment.getRootDirectory().list());

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

public void callMe(){
    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), this.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}`
```

main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Trace

```
11-30 22:37:41.824  13491-13491/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-30 22:37:55.271  13526-13526/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-30 22:37:56.492  13569-13569/by.tq.filemanager.app E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-30 22:37:58.361  13569-13569/by.tq.filemanager.app E/ERR﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
        at by.tq.filemanager.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception you're seeing?

Comment: You cannot expect any result from `findFragmentByTag()` immediately after calling `FragmentTransaction.commit()`. The commit simply commits the transaction to be processed, but doesn't immediately take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Larry is right -- fragments do not get added immediately. One good option, if you have work to do in the fragment after it is attached to the activity, is to override onAttach:

```
public class ContentFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getBaseContext(), this.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

EDIT

From the activity, you can later retrieve your fragment using findFragmentByTag:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mine");
```

The main issue is just that you can't get the fragment immediately after you've added it to your activity. The question of when to access the fragment really depends on when in the life cycle you need to do the work. If you're responding to user input, then certainly you can just call findFragmentByTag at that time. If it's initialization of the fragment, you can use onAttach or onCreateView. You could even call back to your activity from onAttach, so the fragment is telling the activity that it is ready to be initialized.

Does that make sense? If you tell me more details, I can advise you better.

Comment: I have to get access to fragment's methods, is there any ideas?